# How to display subtotal price on product page - magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

i want to display subtotal price on product page. currently it display on cart page.
is there any way so we can show subtotal price on product page.

Comment: What have you tried? are you willing to display cart price or or other price?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would do it.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal()
```

Comment: Hi @nirmal ram thanks for your answer. but i want to display total price on product page. like this http://www.4imprint.co.uk/tag/61/Ballpens/product/300090/Bic-Protusion-Grip-Pen